# Store value in cookie

Tags: cookies

I'm doing a database query in a page, and afterwards I want to store an id - I thought I could do it in $_COOKIE?

But it doesn't seem to work to just create a parameter and set a value to it, like:

```
$_COOKIE['member_id'] = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

How can I simply add a key and value to the cookie array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) like shown below:

```
setcookie(
  $name, 
  $value, 
  time() + 3600, 
  COOKIEPATH, 
  COOKIE_DOMAIN
);
```

*Note:*
`$wpdb->insert_id` AFAIK will always return `false` or `1`, so I'm not sure if that will be of value for your. I might be wrong about that see [@s_ha_dum's comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207340/store-value-in-cookie#comment300778_207343).

Comment: The Codex is inconsistent about `insert_id`, at one point saying what you do and at another saying the autoincrement value of the inserted row is returned, which is what I remember.

Comment: @s_ha_dum You are right about the codex, the latter, the auto-increment value. would indeed make much more sense.

Comment: Just the *name* of the variable makes more sense ;)

Comment: @s_ha_dum Its not like variable names are a guarantee for anything! ;)

Comment: @ialocin can I declare this function anywhere (no need for actions or filters)? Can I then access $name with $_COOKIE['name']? Btw I read that setcookie was deprecated, now its "wp_set_auth_cookie".

Comment: You mean `wp_setcookie()`, which indeed is deprecated, and there you should use `wp_set_auth_cookie()` instead. But `setcookie` on the other hand, which is a PHP function, follow the link to the documentation, isn't, so you can use it. Anywhere is relative, but you pretty much can just use it. @Galivan